# Can I use a 700c suspension fork on a 27.5" frame?

Tags: suspension

I have an old hybrid which is a 700c with a front suspension fork which I don't use any more.

Could I swap that fork over to my new 27.5" bike?

My main concern is the wheel size differences.

Comment: Maybe - you could try offering up the wheel into the fork and see how it fits.  Brakes are the main problem, as well as headset compatibility.  Geometry will be altered, and your warranty could be affected on the new bike.

Comment: Are you bringing the 700c wheels over with the fork?  Or did you want to use your 27.5" wheels with the 700c fork?

Comment: Note that most hybrids with front suspension have ..... the kindest way to say it is .... are built for the lowest cost to the consumer/manufacturer. So the fork that you have on that 700c isn't likely worth the effort.

Comment: What do you want the suspension for anyway? Suspension on a hybrid is often a marketing gimmick as much as a useful feature, but if you like it that's OK. Using a hybrid suspension fork to try and build a mountain bike would be a waste of time and money. It won't have enough travel or enough strength.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, we need to know more about the new bike.

Wheel size - the 27.5" wheel will probably fit, (provided its not a plus or fat), but if its rim brakes, the brake bosses will be in the wrong place. You may or may not be able to find brakes that fit. If Disc brakes it will be fine

Axle - traditionally axles were all 9mm QR, now there are though axles so you will need to make sure the axle is the same

Headset - standards have changed. Anything earlier than about 2010 will be straight 1 1/8", the tapered steerer became available and more and more popular on MTB's and is moving to others.

Is it worth it - probably not. Hybrids don't typically come with great suspension forks, I would not recommend reusing an old fork unless it was a high quality one and the swap was easy (i.e. headset, axle, brakes compatable). Over time the forks degrade, especially if not serviced, and don't perform as well as they used to. A cheap suspension fork that's degraded is probably worse than no suspension.